# How to decode characters to string?

Tags: sql-server

I have extracted text data from a rtf file, there are string in CP 1049

```
lang1049\''ea\''e0\''f6\''e0\''ef\''e8
```

I have tried to decode it to a string but received not string what I know but other characters

```
declare @out table (id int not null identity, string varchar(128) collate Cyrillic_General_CI_AS)
insert into @out(string) select (char(0xEA)+char(0xE0)+char(0xF6)+char(0xE0)+char(0xEF)+char(0xE8))
select * from @out
GO
```

The string should be 'кацапи' .

How to do it correctly?

Comment: So what result are you expected for the above?

Comment: At a guess, your database isn't in the right collation. If it was, I suspect you would get the [resultset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DM8FX.png) you want.

Comment: `select concat('' collate Cyrillic_General_CI_AS, char(0xEA)+char(0xE0)+char(0xF6)+char(0xE0)+char(0xEF)+char(0xE8))`

Comment: yes! that's what I need! thank you. Write your comment as an answer and I will mark it

Comment: @Larnu : as I wrote in other comment:  the string should be 'кацапи'

Comment: The result you need shouldn't be in the comments under an answer, it should be in the question.

Comment: sorry, I have edited

Comment: As mentioned, still looks like the database collation isn't the right one, as demonstrated in my prior [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74874013/how-to-decode-characters-to-string?noredirect=1#comment132136045_74874013)

Comment: May be but it should be independent on db collation, i.e. I'll provide the script to different users with different collations

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using **NCHAR()**

[NCHAR](https://https:/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/nchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

```
insert into @out(string) select NCHAR(0xEA)+NCHAR(0xE0)+NCHAR(0xF6)+NCHAR(0xE0)+NCHAR(0xEF)+NCHAR(0xE8)
```

Alternatively, for UNICODE chars, you can use **convert()**

```
insert into @out(string) select convert(varchar(128), 0xEA)+convert(varchar(128), 0xE0)+convert(varchar(128), 0xF6)+convert(varchar(128), 0xE0)+convert(varchar(128), 0xEF)+convert(varchar(128), 0xE8)
```

Comment: This gives a result no different to the OP's attempt.

Comment: It gives me 'eaoaie' but I  wait as it is in RTF : 'кацапи'

Comment: It is when I perform query in SSMS

Comment: @ZedZip / @Larnu Try using `insert into @out(string) select convert(varchar(128), 0xEA)+convert(varchar(128), 0xE0)+convert(varchar(128), 0xF6)+convert(varchar(128), 0xE0)+convert(varchar(128), 0xEF)+convert(varchar(128), 0xE8)`

Comment: I feel char would not be great as this is not ASCII and char returns a single character, not good for Unicode.

Comment: No, it gives other characters than I expect

Comment: The comment from @lptr works . It is the answer, the rest I will do.